# Need Help Diagnosing This Ajax Request Call

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Need Help Diagnosing This Ajax Request Call.

filtered text  is a text box from an input box further up the page , with filters is a Boolean checking if the user wants to search for anything at all and filtered text is what the user would like to filter by.

```
function GetData(torf) {
        var watever = { "withfilters": torf, "filteredtext": $('#SortOrdersBy2').val() };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/WebService.asmx/GetData',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(watever),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var employeeTable = $('#datatable tbody');

                var employees = data;

                for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
                    employeeTable.append('<tr><td>' + employees[i].CustomerId + '</td><td>' + employees[i].CustomerName + '</td><td>' + employees[i].Engineer + '</td></tr>');
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        });
    }
```

It Goes to this web service code and runs through it on load but still displays the error function.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string GetData(bool withfilters, string filteredtext)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerDataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        List<Data1> Data = new List<Data1>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand
                (withfilters ? "SELECT * FROM MainTable CustomerId LIKE '%" + (filteredtext) + "%' OR CustomerName LIKE '%" + (filteredtext) + "%' OR Engineer LIKE '%" + (filteredtext) + "%')"
                             : "SELECT * FROM MainTable",con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = query.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Data1 data = new Data1();
                data.CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CustomerId"]);
                data.CustomerName = rdr["CustomerName"].ToString();
                data.Engineer = rdr["Engineer"].ToString();
                Data.Add(data);
            }

        }
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return js.Serialize(Data);
    }
```

Any Help Would be greatly Appreciated, need more info let me know.

Comment: Instead of alerting `"Error"` you should use **all three arguments** of the error handler.

Comment: Please also share your attempts at researching the problem and resulting error.

Comment: Failed To Load resource : 404(not found)

Comment: @Andreas thankyou i will investigate further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your webservice you have set the `UseHttpGet=true` which means that this method can be executed using Http GET request not POST

```
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public string GetData(bool withfilters, string filteredtext)
```

However, in javascript you are trying to execute the method using POST from client-side

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/WebService.asmx/GetData',
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
```

**SOLUTION:**

Remove the HttpGet=true from ScriptMethod attribute:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetData(bool withfilters, string filteredtext)
```

Comment: public string GetData(string filteredtext)                   Like that ?

Comment: apologies im being dumb stared at the code for hours xD

Comment: Just like this: 
You need ScriptMethod attribute and the parameter list will remain the same
`[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetData(bool withfilters, string filteredtext)`

Comment: When running the webservice debugger i can use the filters and get the correct data but it doesnt show on the page ill post below what the code looks like involved in this

Comment: <div style="float:right; width:200px; border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px">
    <table id="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Engineer</th>      
            </tr>
        </thead> 
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

Comment: Put debugger; statement inside success callback of your Ajax post code and then browse to your webpage with Developers tool open and see if success callback is executed

Comment: Yea Success Is never called but a break point in there and never reached it

Comment: also put one after $(document).ready(function(){GetData(false);}); and never reaches.

Comment: Launch Developers tool using F12 button and then switch to network tab and then check POST api call status

Comment: @J.Alex If the `success` handler isn't called then the `error` handler will be, hence... Check **all three arguments** which should give you enough hints where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the Continued Help , Went to the Network Tab pressed F5 to load the results and GetData is at the bottom status of 200 and type of xhr , initiator of jquery.min-js:2 size of 970B and time of 2ms

Comment: @Andreas Faile to load resource: the server responde d with the satus of 404(not found)

Comment: @J.Alex in the network tab you can click on the GetData row to get further details like what response is returned from server

Comment: @MohsinMehmood when i click on GetData I get the JSON of the data from my SQL server so that works.